# Unable to submit form data in laravel

Tags: php, sql, forms, laravel

I am using laravel. Below is my form.

```
<h1>New Comment</h1>
<form method="post">

Comment: <input type="text" size="128" name="comment" value="{{old('body')}}" /></p>

    @if ($errors->has('body'))
    <p class="warning">Comment cannot be empty.</p>
    @endif

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

My Route:

```
Route::post('/{id}', 'FilmsController@addComment')->name('addComment');
```

My controller:

```
public function addComment(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    $entry = new Comment();
    $entry->body = $request->body;
    $entry->save();

    return redirect('/');
```

My schema includes 'body'... `$table->string('body');`

I am seeing my warning message when I click submit. The same happens when trying to update as well as add a new comment.

Comment: what's the error that you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the element's name is `comment`, change this:

```
'body' => 'required',
```

To:

```
'comment' => 'required',
```

And this:

```
$entry->body = $request->body;
```

To:

```
$entry->comment = $request->comment;
```

Also, add an action to the form, for example:

```
<form method="post" action="/add-comment">
```

And the route should be:

```
Route::post('add-comment', 'FilmsController@addComment')->name('addComment');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had that initially but was getting this error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: comment (SQL: update "comments" set "updated_at" = 2018-01-11 16:22:45, "comment" = I loved this film!!! where "id" = 1)

Comment: @Dan if you have `body` column, just change comment to body everywhere.

Comment: Thank you Alexey. I just needed to also change it on the html: name="comment" to name="body". I appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change the name="comment" to name="body" as you are validating and require the `body` field which the form doesn't have.

```
<input type="text" size="128" name="body" value="{{old('body')}}" />
```